# clang compiler does not compile code unlike gcc

Tags: c++, clang, c++20, constexpr

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

template<const int *ptr>
constexpr const int *Test()
{
    return ptr + 1;
}

constexpr array<int, 3> ar{1, 2, 3};

int main()
{
    // clang version 15.0.7 - Compile Error!
    // gcc 12.2.0  - ok!!
    constexpr auto x = Test<ar.data()>(); // 1

    cout << *x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

clang compiler messages:

```
main.cpp|18|error: no matching function for call to 'Test'|
main.cpp|7|note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'ptr'|
```

How can I minimally correct the code so that both clang and gcc compile?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I minimally correct the code so that both clang and gcc compile?

You can just use a normal array.

```
constexpr int ar[3] = {1, 2, 3};
constexpr auto x = Test<ar>();
```

You can compile with `-std=c++17` or greater and just use an argument:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
constexpr const int *Test(const int *ptr) {
    return ptr + 1;
}
constexpr std::array<int, 3> ar{1, 2, 3};
int main() {
    constexpr auto x = Test(ar.data());
    std::cout << *x << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works, but the real code is more complicated and it's not easy for me to remake it. But I will try. Thank you!

Comment: @АлексейЛарин You need to edit your question to show something more similar to your real code, then. The bottom line is Clang does not seem to support pointers/references to subobjects as template arguments yet (P1907R1) and there is no generic workaround that covers all possible situations.